# Point Individuals Navigating to Protected folder to Login Page

Tags: php, mysql, protected

I have a folder where I have some protected files (or files i'd like to protect). In order to access the files you must first log-in. I recently realized that when you type in www.mysite.com/myprotectedfiles/admin/ you can preview the list of files and even click to them.

Even though you can not access the information, the fact that you can view the folder contents somewhat bothers me. Is there a way to make folder permissions where you can't navigate to these folders without hitting our login.html page first?

Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an index file for ea folder with a redirects to my login page instead. Its diffucult to get my IT dept to turn off directory listings so this was a fair workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a web server issue rather than a PHP one. If you're saying I can browse to a folder and then get a listing, then (at least in the Apache world) that is the DirectoryIndex that you would need to shut off.

After that you should be good. Depending on how the rest of your admin site is set up, you may need to either put a session check (or how ever you're tracking the logged-in state) in each of your file and if you have other file types (doc, xls, pdf, etc) you may need to put them in a non-web accessible directory and then have some code that will read the contents of the file into a buffer for download, if you don't want someone to be able to directly browse to the files.